# Clicking Add-to-Cart to trigger popup

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, function

I am trying to have a popup only display when I click the .add-to-cart button using jQuery/javascript.

Let's say my popup is "#popup", and the button which will trigger the popup is ".add-to-cart", how do I go about this? I am fairly new to javascript, but I've managed to change a div's color and background the moment a user scrolls 200px, I tried using the same method to make it change properties by clicking without any luck. 
The idea here was to change the property of the popup from "display:none" to "display:block" to use that in my problem here. 
Also, inside the popup there is a button which when clicked, closes that popup again, we'll call it ".continue"

Is this the right way to do it, or is there other ways to display/close this popup?

I would post my code but it's not gonna help much in solving this as I believe this is simple for the experts on here. But here is the javascript i used for my other function that I mentioned which changes properties based on scroll. I suspect I can modify this to be used in this instance as well?

```js
var mybutton = document.getElementById("backBtn");
var mytext = document.getElementById("tilbakeP");
var myarrow = document.getElementById("arrow");
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 200 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
        mybutton.style.position = "fixed";
        mybutton.style.top = "20px";
        mybutton.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.4)";
        mytext.style.color = "#fff";
        myarrow.style.borderColor = "#fff";
    } else {
        mybutton.style.position = "absolute";
        mybutton.style.top = "";
        mybutton.style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
        mytext.style.color = "#333";
        myarrow.style.borderColor = "#333";
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try using JavaScript?

Comment: @Soban Hey, I added the code that I've tried so far, although I have deleted what I tried, but it looks something like that(but the classes and IDs are from another popup, when I tried them, I changed those). Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, if anyone comes across this, this worked by settings the popup to "display:none" in css, and using this code to make it display, by pressing add-to-cart CTA:

```
$('.button.el-button.cta.normal-btn.add-to-basket').click(function(){ 
  $('.installation-popup').show();
});
```